# Android - Starting an application from an ApplicationInfo instance

Tags: android, android-intent

If I have an ApplicationInfo instance of a particular app, how can I make an Intent to launch the app?

I tried

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationInfoInstance.packageName);
```

but it gives an exception. The app is installed so the exception is not due to that.

I think I need to use

```
setClassName (String packageName, String className);
```

Could someone direct me to obtain these two values?
Because most of my apps returns **NULL** for `ApplicationInfoInstance.className;`

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I have an ApplicationInfo instance of a particular app, how can I make an Intent to launch the app?

There is no such thing as "launch the app" in Android. An "app" may have zero, one, or several activities that are in the launcher and are designed to be launched.

You should be able to use `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` on [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to get an `Intent` that meets your needs (or null if there is no such `Intent`).