# Displaying a page of installed app icons in android for custom launcher

Tags: android

So I'm building a custom launcher, I figured out how to replace the default android launcher with my launcher already from another question and have it working so that when the user presses home or back it always brings them back to my launcher.

Now I just need to allow the user to launch the other apps they have installed on their device from my app. Is there any easy way to get a page of app icons that are installed and allow the user to launch them? I'm just not really sure how to do this or where to start?
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the installed applications from [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html):

```
public abstract List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplications (int flags)
```

I found this question regarding launching an application:  [Android - Starting an application from an ApplicationInfo instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4530639/562935).

An snippet from the answer of that question:

> You should be able to use getLaunchIntentForPackage() on PackageManager to get an Intent that meets your needs (or null if there is no such Intent).